# LNK2019 error on CWnd::CreateControl using Visual C++ 2008 Express

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, activex

I am trying to get a legacy program written in Visual C++ 6.0 for Win 98 to compile on Visual C++ 2008 Express on a Win XP machine. The program uses MFC. I have installed an old Windows driver development kit, and am using the MFC headers and libraries from that. When I compile the program, I get a linker error:

```
omiview.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall CWnd::CreateControl(struct _GUID const &,char const *,unsigned long,struct tagRECT const &,class CWnd *,unsigned int,class CFile *,int,wchar_t *)" (?CreateControl@CWnd@@QAEHABU_GUID@@PBDKABUtagRECT@@PAV1@IPAVCFile@@HPA_W@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall COmiView::Create(char const *,char const *,unsigned long,struct tagRECT const &,class CWnd *,unsigned int,struct CCreateContext *)" (?Create@COmiView@@UAEHPBD0KABUtagRECT@@PAVCWnd@@IPAUCCreateContext@@@Z)
```

The offending code from omiview.h:

```
class COmiView : public CWnd
{
protected:
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(COmiView)
public:
    CLSID const& GetClsid()
    {
        static CLSID const clsid
            = { 0xc1c9365d, 0xbdce, 0x11d1, { 0xa5, 0x5d, 0x0, 0x60, 0x8, 0x95, 0x71, 0xfc } };
        return clsid;
    }
virtual BOOL Create(LPCTSTR lpszClassName,
    LPCTSTR lpszWindowName, DWORD dwStyle,
    const RECT& rect,
    CWnd* pParentWnd, UINT nID,
    CCreateContext* pContext = NULL)
{ return CreateControl(GetClsid(), lpszWindowName, dwStyle, rect, pParentWnd, nID); }

BOOL Create(LPCTSTR lpszWindowName, DWORD dwStyle,
    const RECT& rect, CWnd* pParentWnd, UINT nID,
    CFile* pPersist = NULL, BOOL bStorage = FALSE,
    BSTR bstrLicKey = NULL)
{ return CreateControl(GetClsid(), lpszWindowName, dwStyle, rect, pParentWnd, nID,
    pPersist, bStorage, bstrLicKey); }
```

The omiview object is an ActiveX control that displays data from a third-party hardware driver. The driver software is installed and the ActiveX control appears in the list of COM components in the "Tools/Choose Toobox Items" dialog in VS 2008.

The compiler is reading the afxwin.h header and is compiling the declarations for CWnd::CreateControl. Is there a library that I need to add to the project so the linker can find the corresponding object code? Is it some component that is missing in VS Express? Do I need one of the Windows SDKs that didn't install with VS Express? I am new to Visual C++ and Windows programming, so I'm at a bit of a loss with this.

BTW I also have Visual C++ 2010 Express installed, but am using the 2008 version because 2010 would not read the original VC6.0 project file. The program needs to run on Windows XP because it is dependent on legacy hardware and drivers that won't work on a more modern system.

Comment: The error means you did not link in the MFC library.

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP: Thanks. I am not sure which library I need or how to link it. I added C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\lib\Mfc\i386\mfc42.lib to the project but still get the same error. Do I need to do something else to tell the linker to link it? There are many other mfc libraries in the folder. Do I need a different one?

Comment: That MFC lib shipped with VC6. The linking is normally done by a #pragma comment(lib, "mfc" _MFC_FILENAME_VER "d.lib") statement in afx.h

Comment: You probably know that MFC is not officially supported in Express editions, but [have you seen this post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30439/How-to-compile-MFC-code-in-Visual-C-Express?msg=3140483#xx3140483xx) that specifically asks about using VC6 MFC with VS2008 Express?

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP: mfc42.lib and mfcs42.lib are present and seem to be linking. If I prevent them from linking I get lots of linker errors. The problem above is just one external symbol that isn't being found. Perhaps that symbol is in some other library?

Comment: @RogerRowland: Thanks, I had not seen that post. I tried copying over the VC6 MFC and ATL folders and switching the project to use the VC6 include and lib folders. This produces a large number of "unresolved external symbol" errors that seem more obscure than the single one I get using the DDK package.